# unable to run kibana with docker-compose

Tags: linux, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I am trying to run  Kibana with opendistro elasticsearch using the following docker-compose:

```
    version: '3'
services:
  odfe-node1:
    image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:1.11.0
    container_name: odfe-node1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=odfe-cluster
      - node.name=odfe-node1
      - discovery.seed_hosts=odfe-node1
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=odfe-node1
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true # along with the memlock settings below, disables swapping
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g" # minimum and maximum Java heap size, recommend setting both to 50% of system RAM
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536 # maximum number of open files for the Elasticsearch user, set to at least 65536 on modern systems
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - odfe-data1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9600:9600 # required for Performance Analyzer
    networks:
      - odfe-net
  
  kibana:
    image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch-kibana:1.11.0
    container_name: odfe-kibana
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    expose:
      - "5601"
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: https://odfe-node1:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: https://odfe-node1:9200
    networks:
      - odfe-net

volumes:
  odfe-data1:

networks:
  odfe-net:
```

after running the above docker-compose using

```
docker-compose up
```

i get the following error:

```
Starting odfe-kibana ... done
Starting odfe-node1  ... done
Attaching to odfe-kibana, odfe-node1
odfe-node1    | OpenDistro for Elasticsearch Security Demo Installer
odfe-node1    |  ** Warning: Do not use on production or public reachable systems **
odfe-node1    | Basedir: /usr/share/elasticsearch
odfe-node1    | Elasticsearch install type: rpm/deb on CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)
odfe-node1    | Elasticsearch config dir: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config
odfe-node1    | Elasticsearch config file: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
odfe-node1    | Elasticsearch bin dir: /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin
odfe-node1    | Elasticsearch plugins dir: /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins
odfe-node1    | Elasticsearch lib dir: /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib
odfe-node1    | Detected Elasticsearch Version: x-content-7.9.1
odfe-node1    | Detected Open Distro Security Version: 1.11.0.0
odfe-node1    | /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml seems to be already configured for Security. Quit.
odfe-node1    | Unlinking stale socket /usr/share/supervisor/performance_analyzer/supervisord.sock

odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:12Z","tags":["warning","plugins-discovery"],"pid":1,"message":"Expect plugin \"id\" in camelCase, but found: opendistro-notebooks-kibana"}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:22Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":1,"message":"Plugin \"telemetryManagementSection\" has been disabled since the following direct or transitive dependencies are missing or disabled: [telemetry]"}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:22Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":1,"message":"Plugin \"newsfeed\" is disabled."}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:22Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":1,"message":"Plugin \"telemetry\" is disabled."}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:22Z","tags":["info","plugins-service"],"pid":1,"message":"Plugin \"visTypeXy\" is disabled."}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:26Z","tags":["warning","legacy-service"],"pid":1,"message":"Some installed third party plugin(s) [opendistro-alerting, opendistro-anomaly-detection-kibana, opendistro_index_management_kibana, opendistro-query-workbench] are using the legacy plugin format and will no longer work in a future Kibana release. Please refer to https://ela.st/kibana-breaking-changes-8-0 for a list of breaking changes and https://ela.st/kibana-platform-migration for documentation on how to migrate legacy plugins."}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:27Z","tags":["info","plugins-system"],"pid":1,"message":"Setting up [38] plugins: [usageCollection,telemetryCollectionManager,kibanaUsageCollection,kibanaLegacy,mapsLegacy,timelion,share,legacyExport,esUiShared,bfetch,expressions,data,home,console,apmOss,management,indexPatternManagement,advancedSettings,savedObjects,opendistroSecurity,visualizations,visualize,visTypeVega,visTypeTimelion,visTypeTable,visTypeMarkdown,tileMap,inputControlVis,regionMap,dashboard,opendistro-notebooks-kibana,charts,visTypeVislib,visTypeTimeseries,visTypeTagcloud,visTypeMetric,discover,savedObjectsManagement]"}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:28Z","tags":["info","savedobjects-service"],"pid":1,"message":"Waiting until all Elasticsearch nodes are compatible with Kibana before starting saved objects migrations..."}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:29Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"Request error, retrying\nGET https://odfe-node1:9200/_nodes?filter_path=nodes.*.version%2Cnodes.*.http.publish_address%2Cnodes.*.ip => connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.3:9200"}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:31Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: https://odfe-node1:9200/"}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:32Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:32Z","tags":["error","savedobjects-service"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes."}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:33Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: https://odfe-node1:9200/"}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:33Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:35Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: https://odfe-node1:9200/"}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:35Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:37Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: https://odfe-node1:9200/"}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:37Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:40Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: https://odfe-node1:9200/"}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:41Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:42Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: https://odfe-node1:9200/"}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:42Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:45Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: https://odfe-node1:9200/"}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-09-05T11:04:45Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
odfe-kibana exited with code 137
odfe-node1 exited with code 137
```

i donn know why i am always got this exit status with those only two services running with docker-compose
so if anyone had the same issue or can help, please feel free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exit code 137 indicates that the container was terminated due to an out of memory issue.
Try adding

```
ulimits:
  memlock:
    soft: -1
    hard: -1
```

to Kibana service as well.

Comment: thank u for ur response, i have added the above directive to the kibana service but it was already added to the opendistro service before,  unfortunately i still face the same error like before

Comment: ES_JAVA_OPTS:   -Xms2g -Xmx2g
I assume 1gb is not enough for elastic so at least up it up to 2gb or 4gb

Comment: i have upgraded my host machine from 2 GB to 4 GB and changed kibana to use 2 GB, it seems solved the problem but the host machine itself was hanged and i could not navigate through commandline anymore,  maybe should i upgrade it with more GB

Comment: having a bit more RAM would solve it, and please upvote the answer if possible.

Comment: yes, but decreasing the kibana heap again to 1 instead of two, and letting host machine as 4GB, as u know: the heap will reserve more memory and i have started another docker containers, so this will make the host machine ran out of storage, so i have updated ur answer above to help others. and i'd like to thank u very much for ur effort